# To develop a VNC server applet using the VNCJ library

Tags: java, applet, remote-access, vnc, vnc-server

I need to develop an applet using vncj such that the applet can act as a VNC server and the system can be viewed by other using VNC  viewer.

A sample applet is provided in the this site

http://vncj.com/default.aspx

but they do not want to use it as they have some licensing issues and so was asked to develop the same.

I do not know where or how to start.Anyone with some information kindly help.